# Query meta data in taxonomony using plugin Advanced custom fields

Tags: wordpress, meta, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I want to run a query in wordpress to find all local services posts in a taxonomy called local area by the meta data. I have created a custom field using the advanced custom field plugin with the field name as area_code. I also have a drop down select box with service types.

```
  <?php
                    $args = array(
                   'post_type' => 'local_service',
                   'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                   'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'or',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'service_type',
                    'field'    => 'name',
                    'terms'    => array( $catagory ),

                    ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'local_area',
                    'meta_key'   => 'area_code',
                    'meta_value' => $ons_code,
                    'meta_compare' => '=',

                        ),

                    ), 

                );


        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

         ?>
```

Comment: Should `'area-code'`not be area_code` because by default ACF uses underscores for keys.

Comment: Yes your right. Thank you.